# Using for..in to loop through an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use for..in loop to select the objects within a variable and it doesn't show up the necessary Li objects.

```
var mUlLi = $(mUl).find('>li');      //select all li's in main Ul   
var listLength = $(mUlLi).length;
if(listLength >0 ){
    /*for(i=0;i <listLength; i++) {
        console.log(mUlLi[i]);   // works fine show the li objects  
    }*/
    for(var obj in mUlLi) {
        console.log(obj);   // show's diff objects
    }
}
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: The DOM objects in a jQuery object are NOT properties of the jQuery object that can be iterated with `for/in`.

Comment: Meh, always nice to see an answer getting accepted that was not only posted later but also didn't contain the answer the OP wanted for most of the time. Btw, @user1184100, you should really change your nick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has an [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) that does the same thing.

```
$(mUl).find('>li').each(function(){ //for each of the elements found
    console.log(this);              //in here, "this" is the DOM element <li>
});
```

If you used a `for in` on a jQuery object, you'd also be looping through the jQuery methods and properties.

However, if you really want to do a `for` loop on the elements you got from that jQuery (because you didn't want to use `each()`), then do it directly:

```
var nodes = $(mUl).find('>li'),
    nodesLength = nodes.length,
    i, node;

for(i=0,i<nodesLength;i++){
    node = nodes[i];
}
```

Comment: No need to extract the array first - jQuery objects support `[]`, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by using the proper way to iterate over an array - [`for(.. in ..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is **NOT** meant for iterating over array elements/indexes but for object properties - which is not what you want here.

Simply use the **jQuery way** via [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
mUlLi.each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

If you do not want this for some reason (probably not a valid reason!), you could also use a good old `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    var elem = mUlLi[i];
    console.log(elem);
}
```

Comment: Why not? That's the way to go here. But see the second code block in my answer for this case.

Comment: each() is slower than for..in and i have 50 diff elements

Comment: The performance difference is really negligible! And 50 elements are not that much anyway. Why do you think everyone else uses `.each()` if it's *sooooo slow*?

Comment: yeah true :) but still wanted to try for..in ;)

Comment: Read [this complete page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) please with all warnings.

Comment: Well, you cannot use it. Use a regular for loop - jquery objects are array-like.

Comment: sounds to me like you're just to new to jQuery to admit you didn't know about the .each function.  Always remember, the quickest path to ignorance is to deny it exist in one's self.

Answer (score 2):

`mUlLi` (problematic variable name) is not a regular object, is a jQuery collection. You can iterate with `each()`.

```
mUlLi.each(function(){
   // `$(this)` is the current jQuery element
})
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using jQuery's each function?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$(mUl).find('>li').each(function(i,v) {
    console.log(v);
});
```